# Работа с файлами в С++, не считываются файлы

Tags: c++, fstream

Здравствуйте! Следующая проблема: С++ не может открыть файл. Пробовал и абсолютный и относительный путь, и Visual Studio и Clion. Операционная система - Windows 10. Может быть проблема, что нет какого-либо доступа к этому файлу? (На Python файлы нормально открываются и считываются)
Вот код:

```
fstream f;
f.open("in.txt", ios::in);
cout << f.is_open();
```

Собственно f.is_open() возвращает 0.
Файл точно есть в нужной директории.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Читайте документацию на используемую функцию.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что файла нет в директории. Пропишите путь по типу "C:\\\\in.txt" и проверьте. И не забудьте, что для того, чтобы написать обратный слеш в С++ - надо писать его дважды (погуглите, почему так)

Comment: Clion заработал, VS отказывается

Answer (score 0):

Вы не правильно используете функцию.

```
fstream f;
f.open("in.txt", ios::in);
f << ..информация для записи..;
```